# Ember.js: how to get notified when both model AND relationships have loaded?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With the new async router and Ember Data, `setupController` will only be called once the model has loaded since the `model` hook will call `App.Foo.find(id)` which is a promise (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/).

But is there a way to not only wait for the model itself to load, but its relationships as well?

I have route where the model has "childs". I need both the model and childs to be loaded before the transition can continue.

Answer (score 0):

How about using afterModel?

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        // get your data
    },

    afterModel: function(model) {
        // this is fired after your models are loaded.
        // you can access the model too.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim. This won't help in my case though - you can do the same thing in the model and afterModel hooks. afterModel is for cases where you can't guarantee that the model hook will be called. My problem is not Foo itself, but its descendants. The relationship graph is quite complex and I don't know how to find out when it's fully loaded.